# git Status Shows Same File Twice - But with different path slash styles

Tags: backslash, slash, git-status

When I do a `git status`, I see a change list that looks like this:

```
#       modified:   CustomizablePDFs/InvoiceAdapter.php
#       deleted:    "CustomizablePDFs\\Model/AlignContainer.php"
```

If I `add` then `commit` CustomizablePDFs/InvoiceAdapter.php, it will be commited (as it should be) and no longer appear in the status list (good).

However, `git status` will still show  `deleted:    "CustomizablePDFs\\Model/AlignContainer.php"` on the status list. If I do a `git rm` using that file path, it fails saying that the pathspec did not match any files.

How do I remove this entry from the status list?

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git add -A` followed by a commit fixed the problem.

Comment: It is much more helpful if an answer explains _why_ something works.