# Git status shows file twice but different case

Tags: windows, git, git-extensions

I tried to do a search for my issue and the closest thing that I could is this.

[git Status Shows Same File Twice - But with different path slash styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302468/git-status-shows-same-file-twice-but-with-different-path-slash-styles)

But it doesn't seem to be the same issue I have.

I was doing a commit and noticed that the same file was listed twice but with different case.  For instance, `Directory/resource.h` and `Directory/Resource.h`.  Now there is only one file in the directory `resource.h`.  If I look at the file through Git Extensions they look exactly the same.  There doesn't seem to be another hidden file, there is only one file.

So I tried to fix this by removing the `resource.h` file, committing, and then adding the file back and recommit again. Only one file showed up as added.  I thought I fixed the issue, but now if I try to checkout a different branch I get the following error.

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    Directory/Resource.h
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
Done
```

I don't really have any idea what to do from here, I've only been using Git for a few months and I haven't had to do anything more complicated than merging branches and pushing and pulling.

Comment: Related: [Git change case of a file on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793735/git-change-case-of-a-file-on-windows), [How to make Git ignore changes in case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950/how-to-make-git-ignore-changes-in-case)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can happen in Windows if you have a repo with `ignorecase = false` and rename a file without using git. To fix, this should work

```r
git mv -f Resource.h resource.h
git commit -m 'fix case'
```

and this should prevent it from happening again.

```
git config core.ignorecase true
```