# Why git status shows same file twice?

Tags: git, macos

I have changed a file and checked the git status then it's showing me same file twice. I searched the web but couldn't find anything

My configuration
`git version 2.4.9 (Apple Git-60)`
`OSX 10.11.2`

[image]

Comment: This looks like it might be related to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474218/git-status-shows-file-twice-but-different-case). I'd try setting `core.ignorecase` to `true` in your git config. Is `MyAmcat` or `Myamcat` the correct path?

Comment: Thanks James that's a silly mistake by me, I was using `false` intentionally closing the issue.but I will give you + by some other means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the below solution doesn't worked for me

```
git mv -f Myamcat MyAmcat
```

git was throwing error `fatal: renaming 'MyAmcat' failed: Invalid argument`

So I just did a workaround

```
git mv  Myamcat MyAmcatTemp
git commit -m "changed dir"
git mv MyAmcatTemp MyAmcat
git commit -m "changed to exact dir"
```